# MVC How to create a Form that allow me to do ModelState.IsValid only with some fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

this is my model ANNONCE

```
public class Annonce
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.ValidationStrings))]
        [Display(Name = "AnnonceTypeId", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        public int AnnonceTypeId { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int AnnonceId { get; set; }
        public string AnnonceLanguage { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.ValidationStrings))]
        [Display(Name = "AnnonceAdvertiser", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        [StringLength(1000)]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string AnnonceAdvertiser { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.ValidationStrings))]
        [Display(Name = "AnnonceTitle", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        [StringLength(2000)]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string AnnonceTitle { get; set; }        

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.ValidationStrings))]
        [Display(Name = "AnnonceBody", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        [StringLength(8000)]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string AnnonceBody { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "AnnonceAddress", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string AnnonceAddress { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.ValidationStrings))]
        [Display(Name = "AnnonceCountry", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        public int AnnonceCountry { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "AnnonceCountryFlag", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string AnnonceCountryFlag { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.ValidationStrings))]
        [Display(Name = "AnnoncePlace", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        [StringLength(2000)]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string AnnoncePlace { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "AnnonceCP", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string AnnonceCP { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "AnnonceTel", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string AnnonceTel { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "AnnonceEmail", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string AnnonceEmail { get; set; }

        public bool AnnonceVisible { get; set; }
        public bool AnnonceDelete { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "InsertDate", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.Shared))]
        public DateTime AnnonceDate { get; set; }
        public string AnnonceIpAdress { get; set; }

        public string AnnoncePhotoBis { get; set; }

        public string AnnoncePhoto750 { get; set; }

        public string AnnoncePhotoReal { get; set; }

        public int AnnonceVisitorAdded { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "AnnonceCoTime", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        public string AnnonceCoTime { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "AnnonceCoType", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        public string AnnonceCoType { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "AnnonceCoYear", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        public string AnnonceCoYear { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "AnnonceCoQuali", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        public string AnnonceCoQuali { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "AnnonceCoPosit", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
        public string AnnonceCoPosit { get; set; }

        public virtual AnnonceType ParentAnnonceType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AnnonceVisitor> ListAnnonceVisitors { get; set; }

    }
```

And i create a form in order to modify only some of the fields..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AnnonceStep2", "Annonce", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "AnnonceStep2", role = "form", onsubmit = "$('#creationloading').show(); $('#creationform').hide(); $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');", @class = "sky-form" }))
            {


                            <section>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <i class="icon-append icon-address-book"></i>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AnnonceCoTime, new { @class = "inputplaceholderviolet wid100x100", placeholder = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoTime).ToHtmlString()), onfocus = "this.placeholder = ''", onblur = "this.placeholder = '" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoTime).ToHtmlString()) + "'" })
                                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoTime)</b>
                                </label>
                            </section>


                            <section>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <i class="icon-append icon-address-book"></i>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AnnonceCoType, new { @class = "inputplaceholderviolet wid100x100", placeholder = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoType).ToHtmlString()), onfocus = "this.placeholder = ''", onblur = "this.placeholder = '" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoType).ToHtmlString()) + "'" })
                                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoType)</b>
                                </label>
                            </section>

                            <section>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <i class="icon-append icon-address-book"></i>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AnnonceCoYear, new { @class = "inputplaceholderviolet wid100x100", placeholder = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoYear).ToHtmlString()), onfocus = "this.placeholder = ''", onblur = "this.placeholder = '" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoYear).ToHtmlString()) + "'" })
                                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoYear)</b>
                                </label>
                            </section>


                            <section>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <i class="icon-append icon-address-book"></i>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AnnonceCoQuali, new { @class = "inputplaceholderviolet wid100x100", placeholder = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoQuali).ToHtmlString()), onfocus = "this.placeholder = ''", onblur = "this.placeholder = '" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoQuali).ToHtmlString()) + "'" })
                                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoQuali)</b>
                                </label>
                            </section>


                            <section>
                                <label class="input">
                                    <i class="icon-append icon-address-book"></i>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AnnonceCoPosit, new { @class = "inputplaceholderviolet wid100x100", placeholder = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoPosit).ToHtmlString()), onfocus = "this.placeholder = ''", onblur = "this.placeholder = '" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoPosit).ToHtmlString()) + "'" })
                                    <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AnnonceCoPosit)</b>
                                </label>
                            </section>
}
```

the problem is that i do not how to implement my model in order to be able to modify only the following :

```
[Display(Name = "AnnonceCoTime", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
            public string AnnonceCoTime { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "AnnonceCoType", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
            public string AnnonceCoType { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "AnnonceCoYear", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
            public string AnnonceCoYear { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "AnnonceCoQuali", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
            public string AnnonceCoQuali { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "AnnonceCoPosit", ResourceType = typeof(ViewRes.NamesAnnonce))]
            public string AnnonceCoPosit { get; set; }
```

and having my controller like this :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult AnnonceStep2([Bind(Include = "AnnonceId,AnnonceCoTime,AnnonceCoType,AnnonceCoYear,AnnonceCoQuali,AnnonceCoPosit")] Annonce annonce)
{
```

The problem is that, when i send my form, i got MODEL STATE INVALID because the others REQUIRED fields of my model are not present in my form..
For example AnnonceTitle is REQUIRED, but i do not want to use it in my second form..

So how to implement my model in order to be able to have access only to the fields needed in my second form?

I am new in MVC c#, please can you explain me how to achive this?
Thanks

Comment: 1.Use a view model with only the fields needed from the entity model. That way your view is strongly typed with only the necessary fields. When you're ready to send to the db for processing, just map back to the entity model.

Comment: 2. Don't use the built-in submit functionality; use a custom ajax call and send only the needed fields back to the controller.

Comment: 3. Customize your jQuery validation settings by adding rules to ignore the required fields. You'll have to add hidden fields to the form with name attributes for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ModelState.IsValidField(fieldname)

eg.

```
if (ModelState.IsValidField("username")) { }
```

Comment: In fact the problem is that i have model state invalid because i am using the model annonce and my page does not contains (AnnonceTitle; AnnonceBody. ect) which are REQUIRED! So i need to be able to send my form without MODEL STATE INVALID